# eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 8414160 bytes of memory (of type "heap") in windows system?

Tags: networking, erlang

While load testing of my erlang server with increasing number(100, 200, 300,....) of clients, which also in erlang, I got a some message on windows console if the number of clients exceeds 200. The message is

> *"Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump.
>   **eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 8414160 bytes of memory (of type "heap").** Abnormal termination"*.

This is the problem with windows. But if I test server load on Linux system, it can work for any number of clients until the system load reach to saturation state.

can any one help me to override this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: please any one have any idea or solution, let me know. I tried with all heap_alloc commands. but no chage in resulted state.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change "eheap_alloc" size on windows system to run erlang server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274121/how-to-change-eheap-alloc-size-on-windows-system-to-run-erlang-server)

Comment: are you using single gen_server to serve all clients ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, your app ran out of memory. Probably the easiest way to monitor this is to check out which process is eating up the memory. You can check up with os_mon, or easier still:

```
etop:start()
```