# how to change "eheap_alloc" size on windows system to run erlang server?

Tags: erlang

How to change the **"eheap_alloc"** size on windows? This is for to do load test of erlang server with several number of clients. My server is running successfully up to 100 clients but if it is 200, server works two minutes with good results and then after server crashed and resulted with abnormal termination by showing

```
eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 8414160 bytes of memory (of type "heap").
```

But in Linux it can work for all the clients successfully. How can I over come this problem?

help me some one....

thank you.

Comment: eheap_alloc is the allocator responsible for allocation heap memory. It gives up because windows is not going to give it any more memory. So the question to look into is: How much memory is the client used at the point where it gives up? If you have a crash dump, you can use the  crashdump viewer to look into it.

Comment: About using the crashdump viewer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616101/examining-erlang-crash-dumps-how-to-account-for-all-memory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [1] ?
erl +hms Size

```
Sets the default heap size of processes to the size Size.
```

erl +hmbs Size

```
Sets the default binary virtual heap size of processes to the size Size.
```

with different Sizes ? 
[1] http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html

Comment: My guess is that this will just make the problem worse as each of your 1000's of processes start out larger and thus hit the eheap_alloc barrier earlier.

Comment: ya dude. I tried but no change in results. I got same error again.

Answer (score 0):

When you get this message there is probably some memory leak in you server even it works well at Linux. This can be some sort of "live lock" which locking you from release memory in some circumstances. So best what you can do is look better what eats memory in your server.