# Examining Erlang crash dumps - how to account for all memory?

Tags: debugging, erlang

I've been poring over this Erlang crash dump where the VM has run out of heap memory. The problem is that there is no obvious culprit allocating all that memory.

Using some serious black `awk` magic I've summed up the fields `Stack+heap`, `OldHeap`, `Heap unused` and `OldHeap unused` for each process and ranked them by memory usage. The problem is that this number doesn't come even close to the number that is representing the total memory for all the processes `processes_used` according to the [Erlang crash dump guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/crash_dump.html).

I've already tried the [Crashdump Viewer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/crashdump_ug.html) and either I'm missing something or there isn't much help there for my kind of problem.

The number I get is 525 MB whereas the `processes_used` value is at 1348 MB. Where can I find the rest of the memory?

Edit: The `Heap unused` and `OldHeap unused` shouldn't have been included since they are a sub-part of `Stack+Heap` and `OldHeap`, that plus the fact that the number displayed for `Stack+Heap` and `OldHeap` are listed as number of words, not bytes, was the problem.

Comment: Added some more comments, it doesn't really explain the numbers you are seeing as the discrepancy isn't big enough. Could you maybe upload the crashdump somewhere for me to take a look at?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an module called [**crashdump_viewer**](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crashdump_viewer.html) which is great for these kinds of analysis.

Another thing to keep in mind is that Heap+Stack is afaik in words, not bytes which would mean that you have to multiply Heap+Stack with 4 on 32 and 8 on 64 bit. Can't find a reference in the manual for this but [**Processes**](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html) talks about it a bit.