# How to find a memory leaking process from an erlang crash dump?

Tags: memory, crash, erlang

I have a similar problem to [Examining Erlang crash dumps - how to account for all memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616101/examining-erlang-crash-dumps-how-to-account-for-all-memory), my app crashed with `eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 34385784 bytes of memory (of type "old_heap")` and I can't figure out which process caused it.

According to the Memory tab in the crash dump viewer, Process used is 2153MB, 4but when I sum up all the `Memory:` lines in the `erl_crash.dump`  (which are in bytes, see [guide](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/crash_dump.html#process-information)) the result is only around 285MB. Old heap would be another 62MB, but I think that's included in `Memory:`. Where could the rest be coming from? Usually the app has a total memory usage of around 300MB.

Also at the top of the dump file it says `Calling Thread: scheduler:0` but there is no further information about it. There are only entries for `scheduler:1` and `scheduler:2`. Could they be involved in this or are the other scheduler processes unrelated?

Comment: Is one of the processes in state "Garbing" (garbage collection)? In that case, "the rest of the information for this process is limited" according to the guide.

Comment: Yes, there is one process in state "Garbing" that is also currently in `dirty_cpu_scheduler:4`.